# Speeding up MIN, MAX for SQL with JOINs and about 6M rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization, aggregate-functions, min

I've got table [data] with about 6M+ rows in MSSQL 2008 DB.
I need to get MIN and MAX from that join some tables and group by particular field.

That's the query:

```
SELECT sites.id,
MIN(data.created),
MAX(data.created)
FROM [data] JOIN 
[columns] on data.columnID = columns.id 
JOIN [sites] on columns.sitesID = sites.id
GROUP BY sites.id
```

It takes about 20-25 seconds to run, ideally should be in miliseconds, which I believe is possible with some smart indexing play.

How do I do that?

Currently I've indexes on all JOIN fields, but that looks it's not sufficient.

Thanks

Comment: Is there an index on `[data].[created]`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `sites` table is not needed for filtering, your query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT c.sitesID, MIN(d.created), MAX(d.created)
FROM [data] d JOIN 
     [columns] c
     on d.columnID = c.id 
GROUP BY c.sitesID;
```

This may run faster.  Do you have an index on `columns(id)`?

An index on `data(columnId, created)` and `columns(id, sitesId)` would be covering indexes for the query.  Because the data pages are not accessed, this should also be faster.